# AWS S3 API - Objects doesn't contains Metadata

Tags: ajax, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nested

trying to figure AWS S3 API and failing miserably...

I currently got a bucket which consist lots of videos.

I need to request all the videos as an object, that will have the video meta-data which I set once uploading, and the link to share the video.

Problem is I'm getting the object without any of the above...

What Iv'e got so far -

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'id', secretAccessKey: 'key', region: 'eu-
west-1'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = { 
 Bucket: 'Bucket-name',
 Delimiter: '/',
 Prefix: 'resource/folder-with-videos/'

}

s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
 if(err)throw err;
 console.log(data);
});
```

Thanks for reading :)

UPDATE - found that when using getObject and adding ExposeHeader to the CORS setting I can indeed get the metadata I set.
problem is getObject only works on a specific Object (video in my case).

any Idea how I can get all the object like listObject and have values of each object like I do on getObject?

Only solution I can think of is doing listObject to get a list of all the objects, and then by this result to do for each object an getObject ajax?... rip UX
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to sort out first.

As per the documentation, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property listObjects API returns exactly what is mentioned in the callback parameters. Using a delimiter causes the S3 to list objects only one level below the prefix given. It won't traverse all objects recursively.

In order to get the URL, you can use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property. I am not really sure what you meant by meta-data.

Comment: when Uploading a file, you can add Metadata (key-value pairs) to attach to the file. which is what I wanted to request.

I think I found a way doing so without it tho, the name should be good enough as the url itself should be fixed despite the ending (file-name)

ty tho :)

Comment: apprently that wasn't enough... if you can look at my post update . thanks

Comment: getObject will get you the content of the object. If you are looking to load the video in a web page, then getSignedUrl is the right approach. However, if you want to download the video, getObject is the right way. That being said, there is no way you can list and "get" multiple objects with a single request in S3 SDK. So you list objects first and then getObject for each one of the objects. If you just want metadata, look at `headObject` once.